# Fedora Boot UEFI SLOW

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, uefi

After a fresh install of Fedora 31, the boot time is incredibily slow.

I suspect something went wrong with the boot partitions.
Here is the layout

```
[root@linux Scaricati]# efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
[root@linux Scaricati]# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8:0 0 232.9G 0 disk
├─sda1 8:1 0 200M 0 part
├─sda2 8:2 0 1M 0 part
├─sda3 8:3 0 1G 0 part /boot
└─sda4 8:4 0 231.7G 0 part
├─fedora_localhost–live-root 253:0 0 70G 0 lvm /
├─fedora_localhost–live-swap 253:1 0 9.8G 0 lvm [SWAP]
└─fedora_localhost–live-home 253:2 0 151.9G 0 lvm /home
sr0 11:0 1 1024M 0 rom
```

I tried to re-create the GTP with gdisk:

```
➜  gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.4

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

The disk is as follows:

```
#fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 462271F5-6EEB-4D01-BE4F-10D72CC67108

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    411647    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2   411648    413695      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda3   413696   2510847   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  2510848 488396799 485885952 231.7G Linux LVM
```

The firmware of the PC (DELL Vostro) is set to use UEFI and not legacy Boot. But stil it takes a couple of minutes to start the bootloader.
Maybe the firmware do not read the GPT correctely?

[EDIT]

Maybe I shall delete one partition..the EFI(/dev/sda1) or the BIOS boot ?(/dev/sda2)

Comment: I had similar issue on another PC and it was due to fastboot disabled, it's the fastboot option enabled on the BIOS?

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Comment: Are you using secure boot? If yes - please disable and compare boot times.

Comment: I don't use Secure boot...

Comment: Have you analyzed the boot sequence using `systemd-analyze`? If so, please provide the output of `systemd-analyze blame`.